# image in drawable folder is int data type?

Tags: android

From the web tutorial, I got this code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{
    Context context;
    private int[] GalImages = new int[] {R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three};

    ImageAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return GalImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
    {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
    {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

From the part `private int[] GalImages = new int[] {R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three};`

My question is why the image file can be store in integer data type? and is it possible if I change `R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three` to my other images which are in my device? For example: `file:///sdcard/Phone/abc.jpg`

Comment: That's not the image that's an integer, it's the "file path"/R.drawable path to it that is.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Drawable`'s data type isn't an `int`; your reference to it is an `int`, which you can see in `R.java`.

And no, you cannot change those references at runtime.

If you peek into your `R.java` file, you can see that it is declared `final`.

Example:
`public static final int actionBarSize=0x7f010062;`